# Pretty print sql code from separate file with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Knitr produces a nice, syntax highlighted code when using a code chunk as below.

````
```sql
SELECT column
FROM table
```
````

Is it possible to achieve the same thing but with the sql code stored in a file?
Something like:

````
```sql
read_chunk('mycode.sql')
```
````

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you can use an inline R expression to achieve it:

````
```sql
`r xfun::file_string('mycode.sql')`
```
````

Comment: Wonderful, thanks Yihui. I wasn't aware that you could use inline r expression within code chunks. This enables me to keep my documentation in sync with my code.

Comment: @Rickard No, you cannot really use inline R expressions in code chunks. The inline R expression works here because `'''sql` is not treated as a code chunk in knitr. At the moment, only `'''{r *}` is identified as code chunk (I cannot type literal backticks here, so I used `'`, which should be read as a backtick).

Comment: Downvoted because this solution doesn't work for me. The sql file is correctly read and displayed but not formatted as sql code.

Comment: This does not work in a {sql, eval=FALSE} chunk in v3.4.  It would be nice to have.

Comment: @Chris make sure you don't include the braces, this is for unevaluated sql only so `eval=FALSE` is not needed