# non-R code listings in a bookdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'd like to include bits of code in my bookdown (in languages other than R) that are kept in separate files. Languages include rust, js, html, css, and some configuration files. These are kept in separate files so that I can run tests externally to verify that the system (code + config) I'm documenting actually runs properly.

A simple test version of my index.Rmd looks like:

````
---
title: "Testing Included Code Files"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
    bookdown::gitbook:
        search: yes
---

# Intro

There is some code in a file:

```{r child = 'code.txt'}
```
````

And code.txt contains:

```
function blah

    foo()
    some->other_stuff()

endfunction
```

When I generate the book with `Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"` it includes the content of code.txt, but it renders it as markdown -- the `function` and `endfunction` lines are shown as regular paragraphs, and the body is shown as code because it is indented four spaces.

If I change that to be:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, comment = NA}
writeLines(readLines(file("code.txt", "r")))
```
````

then I can get the verbatim rendering. But I'm wondering if I'm missing something: is there a more straightforward way to do this? And especially, can I get colorized code?

Comment: I think this is essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/24524594/559676. Please feel free to let me know if I misunderstood your question and I'll reopen it. Thanks!